# How to back up VPS

Tags: backup, vps

"It is highly recommended in the event a system is compromised that a backup of the VPS be taken and an operating system be performed." I have no idea what they meant by second part either.

How is this done on linux Centos 6.5 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux in terminal please?

Comment: Do you use LVM? If yes, I'd create a LVM snapshot and transfer it via scp/rsync to another server, or store it in another disk.

Comment: never heard of it will need to do some research thanks.

Comment: Where did you quote this from? Did you make a mistake in doing so? "and an operating system be performed" does not make any sense.

Comment: EXACTLY what I thought! That is exactly what the VPS provider wrote.

Comment: Maybe "restored" is missing or "reinstall". Ask them they should indicate what they meant and help out/give pointers for that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can back up a VPS the same way you would any other server.

On the basic I would recommend copying your important files to another server, or an external HDD.  This can be done with SCP, NFS, Rsync, or any number of other tools.  If the files on your VPS are changing it might be a good idea to set up the backup in a cron job.

A sample command might be:

```
scp -a all/my/files/ root@mybackupserver.com:~/backups/
```

If you want a more robust solution you should look into some enterprise backup solutions such as Crashplan or any one of it's competitors.

Comment: "the same way you would any other server" ?  I was hoping for a command that might save it.

Comment: I added a sample command to my answer, it would be extremely difficult for me to construct a more exact command without knowing what type of backup you are trying to achieve.

Comment: read somewhere you can do bash backup.sh to save as tar file?

Comment: `scp` does not properly preserve all inode attributes. Consider using `rsync -aHAX`.